# Locker Service - Window object instead of SecureWindow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, locker-service

While Locker Service is activated, I have a script that is loaded by the Aura framework.

If I put a `debugger;` to the start of that script, the `this` and `window` objects references the `[object Window]` instead of the secure one. So, when I add libraries on the window object, it is on the unsecured one.

Obviously, when I got the `onScriptLoaded` callback in the lightning component, I am unable to access the libraries because I now have the `SecureWindow` instead.

Edit:
I am able to reproduce using this component:

```
<aura:component implements='forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes' access='global'>
    <aura:attribute name='debug' type='Boolean' default='true' access='global' />      
    <aura:if isTrue='{!v.debug}'>
        <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                               $Resource.resources + '/js/jquery.js')}" />
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

The `<aura:if>` is really the culprit here.

What should I do?

Comment: How exactly are you loading this script? Is there a custom template involved?

Comment: In a Lightning component, I use: ```<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
        $Resource.JsSearch + '/js/CoveoJsSearch.js',
        ...
       )}"

      styles="{!join(',',
        $Resource.XYZ,
        ...)}"

      afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.onScriptLoaded}" />```

Comment: That definitely shouldn't be happening. And you can reproduce this by previewing a Lightning app alone or do you have to be inside some container (like a Community)? Is there any way I can see the code of the library to debug?

Comment: Yes, I am in a Lightning Community. I am on the east coast, could we setup something tomorrow?

Comment: I've upload the file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Tk-54P3h8dTjlqb2hKdGwtZG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've just create a brand new org, with a brand new community and I am able to reproduce.

Comment: Also, in my evaluated script, I don't see the header `function $globalEvalIIFE$(){with(arguments[1]||{}){with(arguments[0]||{}){return (function(window){`. I am trying to reproduce with a simple component, but right now, I am unable.

Comment: @TrevorBliss I am able to reproduce using a simple `<aura:if>` around my `<ltng:require>`

Comment: Ugh this is a regression because one of the underlying APIs ltng:require uses has changed. I see exactly where the problem is, this will be fixed shortly.

Comment: @TrevorBliss can you poke me where when its done please? From another thread, when will we be able to set cookies? I've read this week, but yesterday it wasn't working.

Comment: The fix for this is scheduled for the next patch (next week). Thanks for pinpointing the root cause, made fixing the problem very straightforward. You can now set cookies from inside your Lighting components. Note that you'll only have access to cookies set from within the same namespace by other Lightning components. If you think there's a bug please post a new question with repro steps and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a regression that is fixed internally and is currently scheduled to be released in the next patch. As the OP pointed out, this only happens when the `<ltng:require>` is inside an `<aura:if>`.

**Edit:** This was fixed in the 206.11 patch.